# Adding additional string to variable - PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, concatenation

Here's my problem.  I want to create a function that takes an outside variable that contains an xpath and once the function runs I want to add to that same variable to create a counter.

So I have the outside variable:

```
 $node = $xmlDoc->xpath('//a:Order');
```

Then the function with a single argument that will take the outside variable (`$node`). Like so:

```
function loopXML($node) {
    i=1; //counter variable
}
```

Now I want to add a counter to $node so that it goes through all of the children of "Order".  Outside of the function, I would use:

```
$child = $xmlDoc->xpath('//a:Order['.$i.']/*');
```

But inside of the function, I have no idea how to concat it. Does anyone have any idea how I could do this?

EDIT:
Also, it should be noted that I created an arbitrary namespace already:

```
 foreach($xmlDoc->getDocNamespaces() as $strPrefix => $strNamespace) {
     if(strlen($strPrefix)==0) {
         $strPrefix="a"; //Assign an arbitrary namespace prefix.
     }
     $xmlDoc->registerXPathNamespace($strPrefix,$strNamespace);
 }
```

Comment: Why are you passing `$node` into the function?  How is it used?

Comment: The goal of the function is to convert xml to csv. $node is xml parent xml tag to cycle through. $child is all of the children of $node. I'm having to do this a lot, so I'd like to create a function to reduce redundancy and so I can just include the xpath (or xml tag) that I want to pull.

Comment: Also, why not use the [$xml->children()](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) property on your original node so you can iterate them?

Comment: Because I didn't know about it! Thanks! I'll give that a try and see if it works. I'll post if it does.

Comment: I tried $nodeC = $nodeP->childNodes; within the function, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please provide a small example of the XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` uses the node associated with the SimpleXML element as the context so you can do something like:

```
foreach ($xmlDoc->xpath('//a:Order') as $order) {
  foreach ($order->xpath('*') as $field) {
    ...
  }
}
```

But SimpleXMLElement::children() is a list of the element child nodes so it returns the same as the Xpath expression `*` or to be more exact `'*[namespace-uri == ""]'`. The first argument is the namespace of the children you would like to fetch.

```
foreach ($xmlDoc->xpath('//a:Order') as $order) {
  foreach ($order->children() as $field) {
    ...
  }
}
```

This can be easily refactored into a function.

```
function getRecord(SimpleXMLelement $order, $namespace) {
  $result = [];
  foreach ($order->children($namespace) as $field) {
    $result[$field->getName()] = (string)$field;
  }
  return $result;
}
```

You should always depend on the actual namespace, never on the prefix. Prefixes can change and are optional.

Put all together:

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<a:orders xmlns:a="urn:a">
  <a:order>
    <a:foo>bar</a:foo>
    <a:answer>42</a:answer>
  </a:order>
</a:orders>
XML;

$namespace = 'urn:a';

$orders = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$orders->registerXpathNamespace('a', $namespace);

function getRecord(SimpleXMLelement $order, $namespace = NULL) {
  $result = [];
  foreach ($order->children($namespace) as $field) {
    $result[$field->getName()] = (string)$field;
  }
  return $result;
} 

foreach ($orders->xpath('//a:order') as $order) {
  var_dump(getRecord($order, $namespace));
}
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  ["answer"]=>
  string(2) "42"
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but didn't seem to get it to work. It may be worth noting that I have created an arbitrary namespace already.

Comment: One of the limits is that you will have to register namespaces on each SimpleXMLElement you call `xpath()` if you use them in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out with a lot of Googling and the help of ThW. So to all that helped, thank you. Here's how I got it to work:

```
 $orderPNode = '//a:Order'; 
 $amazonRawXML = 'AmazonRaw.xml';
 $amazonRawCSV = 'AmazonRaw.csv';


function loopXML($xmlDoc, $node, $writeCsv) {
$i = 1;
$xmlDocs = simplexml_load_file($xmlDoc);
$result = [];

foreach($xmlDocs->getDocNamespaces() as $strPrefix => $strNamespace) {
    if(strlen($strPrefix)==0) {
        $strPrefix="a"; //Assign an arbitrary namespace prefix.
    }
$xmlDocs->registerXPathNamespace($strPrefix,$strNamespace);
}

file_put_contents($writeCsv, ""); // Clear contents of csv file after each go

$nodeP = $xmlDocs->xpath($node); 

foreach ($nodeP as $n) {
    $nodeC = $xmlDocs->xpath($node.'['.$i.']/*');
    if($nodeC) {
        foreach ($nodeC as $value) {
            $values[] = $value;
        }
    $write = fopen($writeCsv, 'a'); 
    fputcsv($write, $values);
    fclose($write);

    $values = [];
    $i++;
    } else {
        $result[] = $n;
        $i++;
    }

}
return $result;
}
loopXML($amazonRawXML, $orderPNode, $amazonRawCSV);
```